# Create linkable notification from background process on windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, batch-file, notifications

I want to create a process on a windows box that runs in the background and checks a web service. When triggered by a particular event I want the process to show a notification **which does not grab focus**, to alert the user to the event, and include a link to a web page for them to go to.

HTML5 web notification API seems to fit the bill for not grabbing focus and including links, and I can do the server polling in javascript, but how to initiate it? I've been trying to run chrome or firefox as a background process, but it's either not running, or not able to execute the notifications while running in the background.

Any suggestions for tweaks to this process, or entirely new solutions?

Comment: How is this related to [tag:batch-file]?

Comment: Because I want to run it as a process separate from the browser (albeit leverage some browser functionality). On windows batch files are a common way to do this, depending what the solution ended up being.